# how to get rid of "LINK : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol "_xmlFree" imported"?

Tags: c, windows, linker

I build one DLL on windows with microsoft-visual-c 6.0 including the source code from libxml2. Now I have used some xmlFree() calls in my code and I now get the linker warning LNK4049.

I have not the slightest idea, how to get rid of this warning. I googled, but all info I found was above my comprehension (I use normally gcc under solaris). Is there a simple receipt (add/remove compiler-flag or #define/#undef or similar)?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atww7hec.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting this warning when statically linking against libxml2_a.lib with MSVC 11. I haven't tried the DLL version so I'm not sure if it is affected in the same way.

The solution was to define these symbols in your project or makefile to tell the libxml2 header files to assume static linkage and avoid dll-importing and dll-exporting the xmlFree variable at the same time:

```
LIBXML_STATIC
```

The same applies to libxslt/libexslt too:

```
LIBXSLT_STATIC
LIBEXSLT_STATIC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will add bit more context for others who face similar error like following.
We did libxml upgrade from 2.9.4 to 2.9.14 and we observed following errors which are similar to above .

```
warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol xmlStrcmp imported in function 
"void __cdecl ::updateRunElement(struct _xmlNode *,class xml::XmlDoc &,struct _xmlNode *,struct const &)" 
(?updateRunElement@YAXPEAU_xmlNode@@AEAVXmlDoc@xml@2@@2@@Z)
LINK : error LNK1218: warning treated as error; no output file generated

warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol xmlFreeDoc imported in function "public: __cdecl xml::XmlDoc::~XmlDoc(void)" (??1XmlDoc@xml@@QEAA@XZ)
    LINK : error LNK1218: warning treated as error; no output file generated
```

All the other answers for this error points to set runtime library to /md (Multithreaded dll) or viceversa.

I also tried to suppress these warning by
#pragma warning( disable : 4217 1218) and also by project setting "Disable Specific Warnings" but both did not work as keep giving warnings/errors.

But as @vladimir. (Thanks for the answer) suggested defining LIBXML_STATIC as preprocessor in the project where you are using libxml library either as static or dynamically linked should fix all these warning errors.

[image: Visual studio project property for preprocessor]